# Using Flyway with Hive on Amazon S3, is it possible?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, flyway

I intend to control migrations in Hive database structure on Amazon S3. Is it possible? I couldn't find any reference of supportting Hive. Can you help me?

Comment: S3 (or any backing storage) isn't relevant since the jdbc connection would be just to HiveServer https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/142

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.